# Distinguish Web Browsers From Each Other With Javascript Document Element

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, webbrowser-control, loading, japplet

```
function init()
      {
        // Microsoft Internet Explorer
   alert("test-1");
        if (document.all)
        {
   alert("test-2");
          document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
          document.all.myapplet.style.visibility="visible";
          document.applets[0].repaint();
        }
        // Netscape Navigator

        else
        {
alert("test-3");
          document.loading.visibility="hide";
          document.myapplet.visibility="visible";
        }
      }
```

This javascript code clear loading text after applet loading completely. First condition is for microsoft OS's browsers. Second condition is  for unix and other's browsers. But all browsers give test1 and test-3 alert message. Namely "document.all" isn't knew by all browsers. How can i distinguish browsers from each other with javascript (especially microsoft internet explorer) ?

Comment: Have you tried google? The answers from searching for "using javascript to identify browser" gives many possible solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor')>0;
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;
var isIE = false || document.documentMode;

Maybe this code runs for detecting browser..

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Code snippet:

```
  <script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script> 
  <script src="/jquery.browser.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script> 
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    document.writeln( "<pre>" );
    document.writeln( "User Agent        = " + navigator.userAgent );
    document.write  ( "Browser Vendor    = " );
    if( $.browser.chrome )
    {
      document.writeln( "Google Inc" );
    }
    if( $.browser.mozilla )
      {
      document.writeln( "Mozilla Foundation" );
      }
    if( $.browser.msie )
      {
      document.writeln( "Microsoft Corporation" );
      }
    if( $.browser.opera )
      {
      document.writeln( "Opera Software" );
      }
    if( $.browser.safari )
      {
      document.writeln( "Apple Inc" );
      }
    document.write  ( "Browser           = " );
    if( $.browser.chrome )
      {
      document.write( "Chrome" );
      }
    if( $.browser.mozilla )
      {
      document.write( "Mozilla" );
      }
    if( $.browser.msie )
      {
      document.write( "Internet Explorer" );
      }
    if( $.browser.opera )
      {
      document.write( "Opera" );
      }
    if( $.browser.safari )
      {
      document.write( "Safari" );
      }
    if( $.browser.desktop )
      {
      document.writeln( " (Desktop)" );
      }
    if( $.browser.mobile )
      {
      document.writeln( " (Mobile)" );
      }
    document.writeln( "Version Number    = " + $.browser.versionNumber );
    document.writeln( "Rendering Version = " + $.browser.version );
    document.write  ( "Operating System  = " );
    if( $.browser.android )
      {
      document.writeln( "Android" );
      }
    if( $.browser.cros )
      {
      document.writeln( "Chrome OS" );
      }
    if( $.browser.linux )
      {
      document.writels( "Linux" );
      }
    if( $.browser.mac )
      {
      document.writels( "Macintosh" );
      }
    if( $.browser.win )
      {
      document.writeln( "Windows" );
      }
    document.writeln( "</pre>" );
  </script>
```

Output:

```
User Agent        = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Browser Vendor    = Mozilla Foundation
Browser           = Mozilla (Desktop)
Version Number    = 31
Rendering Version = 31.0
Operating System  = Windows
```